# How to get the financial data using Python (more than 5 periods required)

Tags: finance, stock, yahoo-finance, trading, tradingview-api

I am currently trying to create a stocks database and required long historical financial data. I tried yahoofinance which only give me 4 periods of data. I have paid for tradingview which provide me with longer data. Is there a way for python to pull the financial data straight from tradingview? Or are there any other options available. (I need data for Thai's stocks (SET index))

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I like to use https://github.com/alvarobartt/investpy to get financial data.

Consider using https://github.com/ymyke/tessa, it unifies and simplifies access to investpy (and pycoingecko). It also takes care of caching and rate limiting. (Disclosure: I'm the author or tessa.)